# Create a new array from array with preg_match returned condition

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, preg-match

I want to create a new array from the array with only the preg_match true case.From my array i want to create a new array which contains the string "banner" and assigned it to new $banner=array(), This is my array ($main_array)

```
[banner_title1] => title1
[banner_img1] => banner1.png
[banner_desc1] => bannerdesc1
[banner_link1] => http:/ab.com
[banner_title2] => title2
[banner_img2] => banner2.png.png
[banner_desc2] => sliderdesc
[banner_link2] => http://google.com
[portfolio_link1] => http://test.com
[portfolio_img1] => portfolio1.png
[portfolio_link2] => http://bb.dk
[portfolio_img2] => abc.png
```

From the above array

```
 foreach($main_array as $key=>$val){
 if(preg_match('/banner/', $key) )
 {
echo $key."br />";
 }
 }
```

By this i can get the results with key only containing "banner". But i want a new array like this.

```
 $banner_array= array (
"banner_title"  => array("banner_title1" => "title1", "banner_title2" => "title2"),
"banner_img" => array("banner_img1" => "banner1.png", "banner_img2" => "banner2.png"),
"banner_link"   => array("banner_link1"=>"http://banner1.com, "banner_link2 =>"banner2.com")
```

);and so on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Do this**

```
foreach($main_array as $key=>$val){
    if(preg_match('/banner/', $key) )
    {
     $resultArray[$key]=$val;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have aleady achieved something like that. i want to create new array like

    `array("banner_title"  => array("banner_title1" => "title1", "banner_title2" => "title2"),
"banner_img" => array("banner_img1" => "banner1.png", "banner_img2" => "banner2.png"),
"banner_link"   => array("banner_link1"=>"http://banner1.com, "banner_link2 =>"banner2.com"))`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foreach($main_array as $key => $val) {
    if(preg_match('/((banner_[a-z]+)\d+)/', $key, $m) ) {
        $banner_array[$m[2]][$m[1]] = $val;
    }
}
print_r($banner_array);
```